# jQuery UI Tabs - My first slide doesn't get displayed by default

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

My first tab is set to .ui-tabs-hide by default, so it is being hidden as I hide all hidden tabs.

Below is my code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#slide-container").tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle' } });
    });
</script>


<article id="slide-container">
    <ul id="thumbnails">
        <li id="move-previous"><a href="#"><img src="images/previous.png" width="32" height="64" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#impact-homepage"><img src="temp/temp.png" width="100" height="64" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#impact-inspiration"><img src="temp/temp.png" width="100" height="64" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li id="move-next"><a href="#"><img src="images/next.png" width="32" height="64" alt="" /></a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="slide homepage" id="impact-homepage">
        <img src="images/website-screenshots/impact-homepage.jpg" width="485" height="296" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="slide" id="impact-inspiration">
        <img src="images/website-screenshots/impact-inspiration.jpg" width="960" height="511" alt="" />
    </div>

    <ul id="bottom-information">
        <li class="classification">Website <a href="#">Visit Website</a></li>
        <li class="slide-number"><a href="#">&lt;</a> 1/4 <a href="#">&gt;</a></li>
    </ul>
</article>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The single #'s in the href's were throwing off the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying hide in whole container

Instead of directly applying CSS rules, try:

```
.tabs( "disable" , index )
```